# PreferenceFragment overlaps the Main Activity's Layout?

Tags: android, preferencefragment

I've been on stackoverflow for a week now trying to find the answer to this 'overlap' problem.

Some people don't even use setContentView()??? Others insist on it...

I'm missing something.

[Snapshot of before and after clicking on Settings menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7YoH.jpg)

**SettingsActivity**:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.preferences);

         getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.pref_frag_id, new appPreferences()).commit();

    }


    public static class appPreferences extends PreferenceFragment {


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Load the preferences from an XML resource
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }
}
```

Layout, **preferences.xml**, for the PreferenceFragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}"
             >

    <fragment
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/pref_frag_id"
            android:name ="com.testng.firstapp.SettingsActivity$appPreferences"
            />

</FrameLayout>
```

The 'main' layout, **Main.xml**, in case I'm missing something:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvToDos"
            android:layout_width="206dp"
            android:layout_height="380dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:smoothScrollbar="false"
            android:layout_above="@+id/itemEntryView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/itemEntryView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" >

       <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNewToDo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="editToDoItem"
            android:text="@string/new_item"
            android:textSize="@dimen/smallTextSize" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops.

I had the wrong theme for my activity's manifest.xml file:

```
<style name="Theme.Holo.Light.Panel">
```

Theme.Holo.Light.Panel makes the window floating, with a transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're better off with 2 fragments, one for your initial view and one for your settings view. In the main activity XML, there should just be one FrameLayout. This is where you will put your main fragment and your settings fragment. By having only 1 FrameLayout in your main view and swapping between those 2 fragments, you're guaranteeing that only 1 will be visible at a time. However, I would recommend that you use a separate activity for hosting your settings fragment because I'm not sure that those 2 views have anything to do with each other.

Comment: What are you saying? Is that confusing? You only have 1 possible spot for a fragment to appear, both can't be in that spot at the same time. By putting 1 fragment in that spot at a time, you guarantee only 1 will be visible at a time.

Comment: You should put your edit as an answer and then accept it since you seemed to have found your solution.